# could not create an instance of gradle plugin extension

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I am trying to write `gradle` plugin using `kotlin`. It supposed to work like this. While providing configuration

```
apply plugin: 'appenv'

app {
    srcLink ""
    downloadPath ""
}
```

It should allow to download file from `srcLink` and store in `downloadPath` using task `downloadAll`

I created extension class

```
open class ApplicationEnvironmentExtension {
    val project: Any?

    constructor(project: Any?) {
        this.project = project
    }

    var srcLink: String = ""
    var downloadPath: String = ""
}
```

Create plugin class

```
class ApplicationEnvironmentPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.extensions.create("app", ApplicationEnvironmentExtension::class.java)
        project.task(mapOf ("type" to Download::class.java), "downloadAll")
    }
}
```

And here his the task

```
class Download : DefaultTask() {

    @TaskAction
    fun download() {
        val extension = this.project.extensions.getByName("app") as ApplicationEnvironmentExtension
        DownloadUtils.download(extension.srcLink, extension.downloadPath)
    }
}
```

I build it and add it as `jar` dependency to my project.
To check whether tasks were added I run `gradle tasks`. But during that I get the error

```
Could not create an instance of type com.lapots.gradle.plugins.appenv.ApplicationEnvironmentExtension_Decorated.
```

In stacktrace I get

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.reflect.ObjectInstantiationException: Could not create an instance of type com.lapots.gradle.plugins.appenv.ApplicationEnvironmentExtension_Decorated.
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.DirectInstantiator.newInstance(DirectInstantiator.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention.create(DefaultConvention.java:106)
        at com.lapots.gradle.plugins.appenv.ApplicationEnvironmentPlugin.apply(ApplicationEnvironmentPlugin.kt:11)
        at com.lapots.gradle.plugins.appenv.ApplicationEnvironmentPlugin.apply(ApplicationEnvironmentPlugin.kt:8)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginApplicator.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginApplicator.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:144)
        ... 58 more         
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find any public constructor for class com.lapots.gradle.plugins.appenv.ApplicationEnvironmentExtension_Decorated which accepts parameters [].
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.DirectInstantiator.newInstance(DirectInstantiator.java:44)
        ... 65 more
```

What is the problem? Should I provide some addtional constructors to extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extensions need a default (no-arg) constructor. If you really need to assign a field to a value in your extension, you can use `lateinit var` and assign it after creating the extension in your plugin.

In this case, it doesn't look like you need your `project` field anyway, so you can get rid of that and the constructor. Otherwise if you do need the field, still remove the constructor, but you'll need to make `project` a var with a default value of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `ApplicationEnvironmentExtension` is expecting during construction, so I will assume that it's an instance of the Gradle `Project`.  Try this

```
project.extensions.create("app", ApplicationEnvironmentExtension::class.java, project)
```

The plugin needs to pass the constructors arguments when calling `Project.create()`.  If it is an instance of the Gradle `Project`, then the type of `ApplicationEnvironmentExtension.project` should be `Project`, not the vague type `Any`.